# How to create a time lock encryption

Tags: encryption

I want to encrypt a file such that the decryption will take at least X days on a standard computer. I figure that the best way to do this is to save only a partial key, such that the missing part of the key will take X days to determine by the most efficient technique (brute force or better).

Is there precedent for this type of encryption? Are there any off-the-shelf tools that do it?

Comment: If you do this using a partial key, you can only approach the target of X days - sometimes the remaining part of the key will be found almost immediately, sometimes it will take an exhaustive search of the key space and therefore 2X days instead of X days. If you want "exactly" X days, it would probably be better to run the encryption/decryption key through a slow mathematical function for a configurable number of rounds. Various schemes to derive keys from passwords already do this (see bcrypt, for example). The downside is that encryption will also take X days.

Comment: [Time Capsule Crypto-Puzzle by Ronald L. Rivest](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/Riv99b.lcs35-puzzle-description.txt). Computing $2^{2^x} \pmod n$ is cheap for somebody who knows the factors of $n$ (the one generating the puzzle) and expensive for everybody else. Parallelism doesn't speed it up (beyond the parallelism inherent in squaring a 2000 bit integer) and the runtime isn't random.

Comment: You might want to check a look at this answer https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/606/time-capsule-cryptography

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The traditional answer is computing *2^(2^x) mod n* for a semi-prime n. This has some nice properties:

- It's efficient to computer for the challenger, because there is a shortcut when you know the factors of *n*.
- The construction cannot be parallelized. So the attacker needs to compute squarings sequentially, preventing them from speeding up the attack by throwing more resources at it.

  But the attacker can still exploit the parallelism within a squaring using custom hardware, giving a considerable speedup compared to standard CPUs.
- The number of iterations needed is deterministic. You can't get lucky or unlucky.

[LCS35 Time Capsule Crypto-Puzzle by Ronald L. Rivest](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/Riv99b.lcs35-puzzle-description.txt) has the details, including Java code to generate a challenge.

---

Letting the attacker brute-force a (short) key is not a good time puzzle. It's trivial to parallelize, if you throw twice as much hardware at the problem, you solve it twice as fast. In addition to that, the runtime is random and you can only choose the expectancy value for the required effort (this could be fixed by having a number of separate challenges).

Comment: This isn't perfect, of course. You can't really choose the exact amount of time, just the approximate amount, and it will still very quite a bit based on the resources of the solver. This is still one of the best solutions though.